# Reset view preferences for all mac folders

Tags: macos, finder

I would like to reset the preferences for all my Mac OS X folders.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This would find and delete the files storing view options under your home directory:

```
find ~ -name .DS_Store -delete
```

(And don't forget the `-name` flag — without it it the command would delete everything in your home directory.)

As far as I (and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store)) know, the .DS_Store files mostly store information about folder-specific view options.

Comment: Do these files only contain Finder view preferences, or maybe also some other data (e.g. thumbnail caches?)

Comment: @DanielBeck The Quick Look thumbnails are stored in `/private/var/folders/*/*/*/com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache`.

Comment: Nice read about [where they come from](http://arno.org/arnotify/2006/10/on-the-origins-of-ds_store/).

Comment: [Read this if you want to get rid of .DS_Store files](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-disable-the-creation-of-dsstore-files-for-mac-users-folders/).

Comment: Correct but with some limitations: Finder caches the view preferences of "recently accessed" folders (I have no further details how many & how long, but it certainly does it). So even if you close all open Finder windows instances of "folder X", then delete that folder's .DS_Store via Terminal, then even relaunch Finder (in Dock alt-click Finder → Relaunch) then open "folder X", its old custom view preferences get restored. And if you `ls -ldF .*` before/after removal you notice that `.DS_Store` gets re-created with the exact same byte count.

Comment: To bypass the Finder caching and the subsequent undesired recreation of ".DS_Store" files in some directories, you may need to process your home directory or entire boot volume, while at rest, that is Finder shut down and no instance running. Boot into macOS recovery. Menu → Utilities → Terminal. Batch remove all `.DS_Store` files from `/Users/your-home-folder/` or `/Volumes/Your-Boot-Volume/`. Reboot. Note: Didn't test this myself (never had the need), but in theory this should work for those who need to fully reset the Finder view preferences of MANY/ALL folders on their disk.

Answer (score 22):

To restore a folder to the default view settings,

1. Open the *View Options* panel (*Command-J*, or View » Show View Options);
2. Then **hold down** the *Option* key and click the bottom button. With the *Option* key down, the *‘Use as Defaults’* button will change to *‘Restore to Defaults’*.

Comment: Although the 'correct' answer is great (if you don't make mistakes in copying that dangerous command', this answer is excellent if you don't want to risk Terminal commands.

Comment: This IS the correct answer when doing this for a single folder for these reasons:
+ Fast and easy: ⌘J + click "Restore to Defaults") + The other approach (delete .DS_Store) does (sometimes) not work as Finder caches the view preferences in memory. See details in the comment thread there. + The other approach is beneficial for batch operations.